# AdWords count conversion on click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

I want to count a conversion when a button is clicked.

For this I have moved google's conversion code into my main.js file and I attached the code to a click event:

```
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
    var callback = function () {
        if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
            window.location = url;
        }
    };
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-1234567890/Bhdhdqndqdhwudu',
        'event_callback': callback
    });
    return false;
}
$('#register-container').on('click', '.go90jdj', function(e) {
    gtag_report_conversion(url);
});
```

I have two questions now.

First: What does `url` do in `gtag_report_conversion(url)`, is it even necessary? And what does this part do: `'event_callback': callback`. For me it looks like only this part is relevant:

```
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': 'AW-1234567890/Bhdhdqndqdhwudu'
});
```

Second question, If I attach this code to the click event and it works, it would mean that everytime someone clicks the button a conversion will be counted. But that is actually a problem, because I want to count clicks, which come from a click on a google ad.

To sum it up, would it also count a conversion if someone simply visits the website and is not coming from an adwords ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url indicates to the callback function where the user should be redirected after the conversion is triggered.

In response to the second question. You won't have any problems. The pixel is sent every time but Google Ads will just count the conversions from the users that clicked on your ads.